# Как склонять названия городов?

Tags: склонение

Здравствуйте. Возникают затруднения при склонении городов с определяемым словом и без:
1) В городе Мирном или в городе Мирный?
2) В поселке Айхал или в поселке Айхале?
3) "Требуется специалист для работы в поселке Айхале или в поселок Айхал"?
Коллеги спорят бесконечно поэтому поводу. Поясню - АйхАл - название, заимствованное из якутского языка 60 лет назад. В связи с этим возникает еще один вопрос - считать ли 60 лет употребления этого названия уже не иностранным?
Если у вас будут еще дополнения по этим вопросам - буду благодарна. Спасибо.С ув.Наталья

Answer (score 6):

С "Грамоты":

Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями город, село, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование.

Правильно: в городе Москве, в городе Санкт-Петербурге, из города Киева; в деревню Ивановку, из деревни Ольховки, в селе Шушенском, под хутором Михайловским; у реки Волги, долина ручья Сухого.

Склоняются обе части в наименовании Москва-река: Москвы-реки, на Москве-реке и т. д. В разговорной речи встречаются случаи несклоняемости первой части: за Москва-рекой, на Москва-реке и т. д. Но такое употребление не соответствует строгой литературной норме.

Географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом обычно не склоняются в следующих случаях:

*когда внешняя форма названия соответствует форме мн. числа: в городе Великие Луки, в городе Мытищи;

когда род обобщающего нарицательного слова и топонима не совпадают: на реке Енисей, у реки Хопёр, в деревне Парфёнок (однако это замечание не относится к сочетаниям со словом город, поэтому правильно: в городе Туле, из города Москвы; о целесообразности употребления здесь самого слова город см. ниже).*

Кроме того, обнаруживают тенденцию к несклоняемости приложения-топонимы среднего рода, оканчивающиеся на -е, -о: между селами Молодечно и Дорожно, недалеко от села Миронежье, в городе Видное.

Таким образом, правильно будет в городе Мирном, в поселке Айхал.

Comment: А почему *Айхал* не склоняется? По виду он того же рода, что и "посёлок".

Comment: Да, с этим Вы можете спорить. Освоенное русским языком название или нет? Для меня - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если обозначено "город", "поселок" и т.д., то склоняется только оно, а название - нет. То есть, "в поселке Айхал". Если же идет только название, то склоняется одно: "В Айхале". И тут не имеет значения, иностранное слово или нет. С тем же успехом можно сказать "В городе Лондон" и "В Лондоне".
Собственно, в Вашем случае слово "поселок" необходимо только, если Вы хотите пояснить читателю, что такое вообще Айхал (или Мирный). Если же читатель уже в курсе, что Айхал — поселок, а Мирный — город, то лучше писать "В Айхале", "В Мирном".

Comment: **В городе Лондоне**! По правилам русского языка с *городом* склоняется и название.

[ССЫЛКА](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90)

Comment: Да,да! Склонять нужно!

Comment: "В городе Лондоне" даже не звучит.

Comment: "В  городе  Лондоне"  очень  даже  звучит.  Это  давно  освоенный  топоним.  Ещё  лучше  без  "города",  в  силу  широкой  известности  этого  города.  Но  "в  городе  Лондон" - не  звучит.