# Склонение топонимов множественного числа с родовым словом

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

*Совершенно исключено склонение в таких случаях?* То есть "в городе Чебоксары/Мытищи", но не "в городе Чебоксарах/Мытищах" всегда?

Так по крайней мере рекомендует Грамота, судя по ответу Ларf [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/25037/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2). Правда, она всё-таки употребляет слово *обычно:*

> Географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом **обычно** не склоняются в следующих случаях:
>
> *когда внешняя форма названия соответствует форме мн. числа: в городе Великие Луки, в городе Мытищи...*

Не склоняли ли век или больше назад?

Comment: Осторожно замечу, что [поиск по гугло-книгам](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%22&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6vuvW4MXuAhWCz4UKHdIeCNQQ_AUoAXoECAQQCw&biw=1138&bih=522) даёт подозрительно много вхождений "в городе Чебоксарах". Среди них представлены не только весьма солидные издания, но также пособия для учащихся типа "Говорите правильно" и некоторые издания, имеющие прямое отношение к филологии и лингвистике.

Comment: *Ха, интересно!*

Comment: Да, действительно, интересно. "В городе Афинах" — тоже предостаточно (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%90%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%22&ei=Eo8WYML8IZiGwPAPk9-zkAU&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjCzfPEg8buAhUYAxAIHZPvDFIQ8NMDegQIAxBL&biw=1366&bih=657). Даже в Нацкорпусе присутствует: 
В городе Афинах метэков было очень много, но все-таки меньше, чем граждан. [М. Л. Гаспаров. Занимательная Греция (1998)]; Сократ родился в Греции, в городе Афинах. [Л. Н. Толстой. Греческий учитель Сократ (1885)]

Answer (score 2):

> Не склоняли ли век или больше назад?

А как мы с вами отследим это? Нужно смотреть памятники литературы, о Великих Луках - в берестяных грамотах, например. Только там язык разговорный, нормированный литературный появляется гораздо позже. Но я даже представить себе не могу, чтоб было написано ***в городе Великих Луках***. Русский язык в основном логичен (кроме исключений, но и они объяснимы), слова в словосочетаниях согласуются в роде, числе и падеже, город - ед.ч., Великие Луки, Мытищи - множ.ч. - отсутствует согласование, значит, это несогласованное приложение, т.е. название неизменяемое.

Правило согласования топонимов с родовыми понятиями в полном соответствии с принципом "узнавания" и соответствия внешней формы названия и родового слова. Поэтому без слова *город* мы такие названия склоняем, как все изменяемые существительные, а  с ним - не склоняем, чтобы не нарушить согласование и чтобы название "узнавалось".

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!

Answer (score 1):

> Не склоняли ли век или больше назад?

Трудно сказать... Манера предварять топоним родовым словом появилась уже в советское время. Вот у меня в руках репринт справочника "Россiя" Брокгауза и Ефрона 1913 г. (типа дополнительного тома к энциклопедии).

Я им часто пользуюсь, сейчас ещё раз просмотрел наугад несколько подходящих страниц... Нету там "города Москва/Москвы". Есть просто Москва, CПб, Нижний. То же и про Чебоксары. Другие "подозрительные" города (Сочи, Великие Луки) искать бесполезно, не губернские они... Чебоксары тоже город уездный, но он хоть крупный по тем временам.

Comment: Спасибо, Бегемотус! Римма и grizzly нашли много случаев склонения, это очень любопытно. ;)